# Russian equivalents of English idiom "what a ..."?

Tags: одним-словом, выражения, идиомы

E.g. `What a beautiful day!` or `What a jerk!`. The phrase doesn't have in general any positive or negative connotation, but is just a general exclamation about the perceived (large) magnitude of something, good or bad. (`What a generous offer!`, `What a terrible surprise!`)

Of course one could also use any of the above sarcastically, inverting the meanings.

Anyway, my guess is that one might say something like `(Вот) так красивый день!` or `(Вот) такой красивый день!` in Russian to mean something similar, but really I have no idea.

Comment: well, it's hardly can be call an idiom. Unless, you know, everything is idiom.

Comment: @shabunc: I disagree. This exclamatory form is the textbook example of an idiom. Your suggestion that if this is an idiom then "everything" is an idiom is preposterous.

Comment: To be fair to both sides, I honestly don't know the exact linguistic definition of idiom, so even if it turns out to be one, the OP used the correct term only by accident. Basically because it doesn't seem to translate directly, that suggested to me that it's meaning doesn't follow literally from the rest of the rules of the language. Also it seems similar if not entirely equivalent to expressions like "Such a... " in English (e.g. "Such a waste!"), or "was für ..." in German, neither of which translates directly to each other. So I decided to call it an idiom for lack of knowing a better term

Answer (score 12):

In general we say

> **Какой** прекрасный день, какой чудесный пень, какой чудесный я и песенка моя!(a famous song from the cartoon )

But there are variations: speaking negatively about a person we can use

> Какой подлец! And **Каков** подлец! **Ну и** подлец!

Besides we use «Что за» plus noun, or noun phrase

> Ну **что за** шейка, что за глазки! Какие перышки, какой носок!(from the fable by Krylov.)

Answer (score 8):

Pronoun **какой (же)**, with **же** making a phrase more emphatic, would fit universally

> **Какой** прекрасный день!  - **What a** beautiful day
>   **Какой** негодяй! - **What a** scoundrel

But in negative contexts **какой** sounds pretty sterile and mincing (unless said with a contemptuous intonation which doesn't translate through writing) and is usually given up in favor of **вот (это/же)** and **ну и**

> **Ну и** тяжёлый (же) денёк сегодня выдался - **What a** difficult day i had
>   today
>   **Вот (же)**/**Ну и** мразь! - **What a** jerk!

Comment: вопрос к носителям русского - частица **`вот`** во фразах типа **`вот гад!`** может ли принимать форму **`от`** - **`от гад!`** ?

Comment: Нет. «От» — это уже предлог. Ну или умышленное стилистическое искажение, присущее жителям деревни (но никогда не видел, чтобы это передавалось на письме).

Comment: @Arhad значит это скорей всего украинизм, я никогда не говорю в таких контекстах **вот**, только **от**

Comment: Вряд ли. «Вот» по-украински будет «ось». Для проверки перевёл в составе предложения: https://translate.google.com/#ru/uk/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C!.

Comment: @Arhad **от** - это разговорная форма, кроме того, что я её слышу в речи, она и в [словаре зафиксирована](http://sum.in.ua/s/ot), и стилистически она в некоторых контекстах звучит более уместно, чем **ось**, мой вопрос вызван тем, что я никогда не осознавал, что это украинизм, так как не было возможности и задачи проверить её употребляемость за пределами Украины

Comment: @Arhad: [Пример употребления "от"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8khePIWIzqg&t=12m18s)

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что в отрицательном значении после "ну и..." слово часто стоит в уменьшительной форме, плюс соответствующая интонация: "Ну и денёк!"; "Ну и погодка!" (прямо как у нас сейчас, ага).